# In-app purchase fails after telling "item already bought" message

Tags: ios, ios5, in-app-purchase

I am building an iOS app and trying to implement an in app purchase (non-consumable).

All the bundle IDs etc. are set up and working, and I can see my product as valid when I fetch the Apple Store servers. However, while testing, I am getting failed transactions at the paymentQueue callback.

Here is what happens in the iOS simulator step by step:

1. A message box asks "would you like to buy .. for $0.99?" which is correct
2. I click Yes.
3. After about a second it says that I've already bought it (correct, I test-bought it initially while debugging). I click OK.
4. It complains about a login requirement (it says something like MZFinance_LoginRequired, I think its a missing string identifier.) I click OK.
5. App Store login box pops up and I enter my test account credentials.
6. My breakpoint in Xcode is hit, with the transaction state *SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed*.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
NSArray* arr = response.products;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
    SKProduct* product = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"<<my in app purchase id which is correct and working>>"]){
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for (SKPaymentTransaction* ta in transactions) {
    switch (ta.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            receipt = [ta transactionReceipt];
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(validateFromServer) withObject:nil];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self purchaseFailed];
            break;
    }

    if(!ta.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing){
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:ta];

    }
}
```

}
}

`[self purchaseFailed]` always gets hit, which just notifies the user. What can be wrong here? (I am new to iOS and -obviously- iOS in app purchases).
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** My test account credentials are correct, as I am getting a different (invalid login) message if I type it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time struggling with it, I've noticed that I'm not encountering any problems in production. It was probably a problem with the sandbox servers.

Answer (score 1):

sorry about the late answer and I know you already solved yours, but I had this problem too. My solution was to automatically run the restore purchase method since that seemed to work.

Thanks